# Solving an equation with summation in Matlab

Tags: summation, systems-of-equations, matlab

I have to solve the equation below in MATLAB. Both $u$ and $\lambda$ are vectors of same size. How do I do this?

$\displaystyle f(\tau)=1+ \sum_{i=1}^n{\frac {u_i^2}{\lambda_i-\tau} = 0}$

Comment: And thus $\;u_i,\lambda_i\;$ are the entries of the vectors $\;u,\lambda\;$ resp.? And $\;\tau\;$ is a scalar? And what **exactly** do you have to "solve" for? For $\;u_i,\,\lambda_i\,,\,\tau....$\;?

Comment: We have to solve for all possible $\tau$

Comment: I don't understand: **who** is the variable here for which we have to solve? If $\;\tau\;$ , then $\;u,\,\lambda\;$ are *fixed*, known vectors?

Comment: @DonAntonio : it's $\tau$ (see my answer).

Comment: In fact this second solution would work if the equation was $\displaystyle f(\tau)=1-\tau+ \sum_{i=1}^n{\frac {u_i^2}{\lambda_i-\tau} = 0}$. Are you sure of the formula you have given, because I am almost sure that the $\lambda_i$s come from an eigenvalues issue...

Comment: Why don't you give information about the motivation for your study, and what you have attempted ?

Comment: Have you checked that your formula does not begin with $f(\tau)=1-\tau+\cdots$ ?

Comment: The equation I've given is called secular equation and is popular in Linear Algebra. I was having trouble coding it in MATLAB and the answer below has solved it. There is no mistake in the statement of the problem @JeanMarie

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Rama. Now that you have recalled the name "secular equation" I had forgotten (this name was given by astronomers), I have had a quick look at a marvelous book: "Numerical Linear Algebra" by Loyd TREFETHEN and David BAU (SIAM 1997) where, as I had a vague remembrance, they solve the secular equation by very efficient eigenvalue methods.

Comment: Have a look at (http://www.math.unipd.it/~dottmath/corsi2012/lecturenotes/Meurant/Chap12.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equation

$$\tag{0}\displaystyle f(\tau)=1+ \sum_{i=1}^n{\frac {u_i^2}{\lambda_i-\tau} = 0}$$

can be considered as giving the abscissas of intersection points of the curve of function $g$ defined as follows:

$$g(\tau):=y=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {u_i^2}{\lambda_i-\tau} \ \ \text{with horizontal line (H):} \ \ y=-1.$$

See an example on the figure below, with $\lambda_i=2,3,5,8$ and $u_i^2=1,4,9,1$.

One can check easily that $g$ is increasing, because $g'(\tau)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac {u_i^2}{(\lambda_i-\tau)^2} >0$ on all intervals on which it is defined; and that also $\lim_{\tau \rightarrow \infty}g(\tau)=0$ and $\lim_{\tau \rightarrow -\infty}g(\tau)=0.$

There are always $n$ real roots to such an equation, for a kind of "topological" reason (due to the properties of $g$), that I give in a rather sketchy way, :

There are $n$ vertical asymptotes. Thus the curve has $n+1$ branches. $n$ of these branches cut the horizontal line (H) with equation $y=-1:$

- the $(n-1)$ branches in the open intervals $I_k=(\lambda_k,\lambda_{k+1})$ vary  from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$
- the rightmost branch in $(\lambda_n, + \infty).$
- (the leftmost one does not intersect line (H)).

Thus, use Newton's method (or plainly "fsolve" in Matlab) $n$ times

- in each of the $(n-1)$ intervals $I_k$, for example with initial point $\dfrac{\lambda_k+\lambda_{k+1}}{2}$.
- for interval $(\lambda_n, + \infty)$, for example with initial point $\lambda_n+1$.
  [image]